# How to match the following strings using Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex

Using Python Regex, I was wondering

1. how to match the patterns
   `("Exercises...)` and
   `("Chapter...)`
2. how to replace `("Exercises...)`
   with `("Exercises...))`, and
   `("Chapter...)` and `("Chapter...`.

For example:

`("Exercises, 31" "#42")` is converted to `("Exercises, 31" "#42"))`

`("Chapter 2 I Positive Borel Measures, 33" "#44")` to `("Chapter 2 I Positive Borel Measures, 33" "#44"`

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to do... add a ')' after Exercises, and delete it after 'Chapter'?

Comment: @Robus: Yes. That's is what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\("Exercises.*?\))', r'\1)', '("Exercises, 31" "#42")')
'("Exercises, 31" "#42"))'
>>> re.sub(r'(\("Chapter.*?)\)', r'\1', '("Chapter 2 I Positive Borel Measures, 33" "#44")')
'("Chapter 2 I Positive Borel Measures, 33" "#44"'
```

Comment: Thanks! What is "r" meaning in "r'(\("Exercises.*?\))'"?

Comment: From http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals: "When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string", so the string `"\n"` contains a newline character, the raw string `r"\n"` contains a backslash followed by an `n`.  You should always use raw string for regular expressions in Python.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering the meaning of ".*?". Is it any character (.) repeating itself 0 or more times, or is it a sequence of characters with  arbitrary length and where the characters can be different from each other?

Comment: `.` matches any character except newlines, `.*` matches as many arbitrary characters as possible (greedy), and `.*?` as few arbitrary characters as possible (where a match still occurs). So the `.*` in `a.*c` will match `bccc` in `abcccc`, but if the pattern were `a.*?c` the `.*?` would only match `b`.

Comment: Thanks! So using `(\("Exercises.*?\))` to match in `("Exercises, 31" "#42")`, will it only matches `("Exercises,`, because the rest is not repeating `,`?

Comment: No, the characters can be different from each other, the reason for using `.*?` here is so that the pattern would only match up to the first `)`.  If you use `.*` then if you had something like `("Exercises...") ("Chapter...")` it would match from the beginning of the string to the second `)`, so the result after replacement would be `("Exercises...") ("Chapter..."))` instead of `("Exercises...")) ("Chapter...")` as expected.